# Quadrupole moment of Kerr spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, multipole-expansion, kerr-metric

In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.99.044005), the Kerr black hole is described as having quadrupole moment of $q=J^2/M$ (which means $q=a^2M$ using $J=aM$) whereas in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4150) it says in the abstract that the limiting case of Kerr is $q=0$. and finally [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2007) says $q=-a^2M^3$ (I think this is due to a different definition of $a$ though, as they say $a=J/M^2$). Which one is correct? Perhaps in the second paper $q=0$ in the approximation they take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper of Bini et al. (2009) discusses a metric where the symbol $q$ stands for a quadrupole ***parameter***. The origin of $q$ is chosen so that it can be understood as parametrizing the deviation from Kerr space-time. On the other hand, the Kerr metric has the magnitude of the quadrupole moment, as precisely defined by [Hansen (1974)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1666501), equal to $Q = a^2 M$.

However, you can use different definitions of the multipoles, and in particular, different sign conventions. This is the case of the paper of Bambi & Barrausse (2011) you refer to, where they use the signature convention where a positive $Q$ refers to a prolate source/field and a negative $Q$ to an oblate source/field. (You have misread their formula which reads $Q \equiv -J^2/M = -a^2 M$).

Comment: Thanks, that answers the Bini paper question. Where did you find the formula in the Bambi paper? I was reading the formula just below eqn (10)

Comment: @supercoolphysicist In the abstract and, for instance, in equation (1). Note that they use the symbol $a$ in a somewhat different meaning, their $a$ is dimensionless, which is in contrast to the usual definition of the spin parameter that differs by a factor of $M$ and has the dimension of mass (length).